# Add string from list to url for API get request

Tags: json, string, url, int, python-requests

Hi I have an API get request that retrieves numbers that I put into a list. I then want to loop over that list, adding every number in the list to a separate new get request. The code I have so far is:

```
for evt in eventList:
    main_api = 'https://api.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events/json?'
    print (evt)
    evt = str(evt)
    url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({evt})
    print (url)

    r15 = s.get('url')
    r16 = r15.json()
    print ('Event:' + ' ' + 'r16')
```

How can I get the number from eventList into the url of the get request like so:

```
s.get'https://api.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events/488990433530010'
```

Comment: You just need to string format the new url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just need to format the new url and use it for the next request -

```
import requests

for evt in event_list:
    ...
    new_url = 'https://api.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events/{0}'.format(evt)
    new_request = requests.get(new_url)

    # do something with new_request
    ...
```